# Find out the currently running queries in teradata using SQL instead of viewpoint

Tags: teradata

I want to find out what are the queries that are currently under execution specific to a user or a group . I don't want to use view point . I need to achieve this functionality using a SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the SQL for a session currently active without using Viewpoint you will need to use the PMPC APIs (which I believe are what Viewpoint might be using as well) to obtain that information from the database.

**Step 1: Obtain Input Values for MonitorSQLText() from MontiorSession()**

```
SELECT HostID
     , SessionNo
     , RunVprocNo 
  FROM TABLE(MonitorSession({HostID}, {UserName}, {SessionNo})) AS T2;
```

`HostID` of -1 will include all hosts

`UserName` of '*' will include all users

`SessionNo` of 0 includes all sessions

You should provide at least one of those values to narrow your search.

**Step 2: Obtain SQLText for the Session you are interested in**

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE (MonitorSQLText({HostID}, {SessionNo}, {RunVprocNo})) AS T2;
```

Use the `HostID`, `SessionNo`, `RunVprocNo` from the first step.

I tried to put the values from Step 1 into a Volatile Table and a CTE to feed step 2 dynamically. When I did the database responded with an error indicated that `MonitorSQLText()` could not be run in variable mode. This coincides with the documentation indicating that this API in particular must be used in 'constant mode'.

This should work on TD 14+ and possibly TD 13.10.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
select * from dbc.SessionInfo;
```

you'll have a list of request with their user and group

I hope to help you

Comment: SessionInfo doesn't have the actual SQL.

Comment: yeah i wan't the currently running query . SessionInfo doesn't have information at SQL level. tried using DBQL log tables but they are updated only when a query is done or aborted. 
I wan't to know currently running queries and since when the query is running

Answer (score 2):

The PMon-API used by Viewpoint is also available as [SQL-functions](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_00/Database_Management/B035_1090_015K/System_PMPC_APIs.006.199.html), e.g. this is returning info about all currently logged on sessions:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE (MonitorSession(-1,'*',0)) AS dt;
```

You can check the PEState or AMPState column to find active queries.